# Check field type in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a loop in columns and check field type.

```
for(i in names(SQLQUERYOUTPUT)){
  abc<- sapply(SQLQUERYOUTPUT[i], class)
  print(abc)  
  if is.numeric(abc)
  {
     min(SQLQUERYOUTPUT[i])
  }

  IF is.character(abc)
     max(nchar(SQLQUERYOUTPUT[i]))
  }  
}
```

if column is numeric then need lowest value and if its string then value with maximum length.

Its not working. Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-clauses are not correct. The function class will always return a string, e.g. "character" or "numeric". This means your if-clauses have to look like:

```
if(abc == "numeric"){...}
if(abc == "character"){...}
```